# jquery validate positioning

Tags: html, css, jquery-validate

I'm trying to position the jquery validate message under the select box and text box.  I've almost have it working for "Change timezone" but not for "Submit".  Not sure why the header Email alerts is positioned centered in the fiddle.  It doesn't look that way on my page.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ALUQB/16/

Click both the change timezone and submit button to see what I mean.

Comment: Are you wanting something like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/sajibmahmood/ALUQB/20/

Comment: ohhhh boy.  Yes that is exactly it.  Don't know why I didn't add the div around the other form...sigh.  Thanks!  Create a response and I'll accept.

Comment: Actually interestingly enough the validation never shows up in IE for the timezone.  Works fine for email alerts.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you missed the container `div` for he second tag and you need to adjust your `position` valuues. Here is a reworked example:

[Reworked Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EuGhP/2/)

Comment: Much better with positioning.  However I still have a problem with IE.  Validation is not happening for timezone only.

Comment: I works for me, though email is not properly validated in firefox as well. as far as filling a textbox is concerned it works in IE 7 as well

Comment: Hrmm, maybe an IE9 problem which is what I'm testing.  The textbox for email is fine and works in IE but the html select is not properly validating for some reason.

Comment: Works in IE8 as well.  Looks like it is only a problem with IE9.  I will have to do some digging.